# Is it possible to specialize generics

Tags: c#, generics, casting

I'm having a generic Converter class

```
public class Converter
{
       public static TargetType[] Convert<SourceType, TargetType>(SourceType[] data)
            where SourceType : struct
            where TargetType : struct
        {
            int N = data.Length;
            TargetType[] result = new TargetType[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                // We does this not work, what can I do else
                result[i] = (TargetType)data[i];
            }

            return result;
        }
}
```

Question 1: Why is is not possible to do the cast? What can I do else? Convert.ChangeType is to slow.

Because of slow performance in general I decided to do it in unsafe code. Unfortunately it's not possible to create pointers to generics - as it is widely known. For that reason I created a converter that decides the type at runtime and performs the casts with a lot of if's.

No one question came up. Can I create a generic Convert routine and specialize it in a way, that in some cases I have defined datatypes. I currently don't know how, but maybe I you read the example you get a clue:

```
public static double[] Convert<double, int>(int[] data)
        {
            int N = data.Length;
            double[] result = new double[N];

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (int* data_pinned = data)
                fixed (double* out_pinned = result)
                {
                    int* A = data_pinned;
                    double* B = out_pinned;

                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++, A++, B++)
                    {
                        *B = ((double)*A);
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Below you can find a "small" demo project which shows the performance values of different casts:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class CastTest
    {
        public static unsafe double[] Cast1(int[] input)
        {
            int N = input.Length;
            double[] output = new double[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) output[i] = (double)(input[i]);

            return output;
        }

        public static unsafe double[] Cast2(int[] input)
        {
            int N = input.Length;
            double[] output = new double[N];

            fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
            {
                double* outp = output_pinned;

                fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
                {
                    int* inp = input_pinned;

                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++, inp++, outp++) *outp = (double)(*inp);
                }

                return output;
            }
        }

        public static unsafe double[] Cast3(int[] input)
        {
            int N = input.Length;
            double[] output = new double[N];

            fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
            {
                double* outp = output_pinned;

                fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
                {
                    int* inp = input_pinned;

                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) outp[i] = (double)(inp[i]);
                }

                return output;
            }
        }

        public static unsafe double[] Cast4(int[] input)
        {
            int N = input.Length;
            double[] output = new double[N];
            fixed (double* output_pinned = output)
            {
                fixed (int* input_pinned = input)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) output_pinned[i] = (double)(input_pinned[i]);
                }
            }

            return output;
        }

        public static unsafe double[] Cast5(int[] input)
        {
            double[] output = new double[input.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < input.Length; i++) output[i] = (input[i]);

            return output;
        }

        public static unsafe double[] Cast6(int[] input)
        {
            Converter<int, double> converter = (A) =>
                {
                    return A;
                };

            return Array.ConvertAll<int, double>(input, converter);
        }

        public static void StartTest()
        {
            int[] A = new int[100000];
            int N = 10000;

            var w1 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A1 = Cast1(A); }
            w1.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 1, w1.ElapsedMilliseconds));

            var w2 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A2 = Cast2(A); }
            w2.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 2, w2.ElapsedMilliseconds ));

            var w3 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A3 = Cast3(A); }
            w3.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 3, w3.ElapsedMilliseconds));

            var w4 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A4 = Cast4(A); }
            w4.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 4, w4.ElapsedMilliseconds));

            var w5 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A5 = Cast5(A); }
            w5.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 5, w5.ElapsedMilliseconds));

            var w6 = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) { double[] A6 = Cast6(A); }
            w6.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}: {1}ms", 6, w6.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated to improve the performance.
The sizes for array size and repetitions are real values for me. In fact for testing purpose these values are also a little lower than normally used.

Is there a possibility to do this?

Thanks
Martin

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do the cast because there's no guarantee that there *is* a conversion between the two types involved. What if `SourceType` is `Guid` and `TargetType` is `double`? The compiler basically can't emit a conversion.

The simplest approach is probably to provide a delegate:

```
public static TTarget[] Convert<TSource, TTarget>(TSource[] data,
    Func<TSource, TTarget> conversion)
{
    TargetType[] result = new TargetType[data.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = conversion(data[i]);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Of course this is basically the same as calling [`Array.ConvertAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx)... does that not do what you want?

Yes, there'll be a small performance overhead from calling the conversion frequently - but have you proved to yourself that that performance overhead is a problem? I would at least *try* using `Array.ConvertAll` as a first attempt.

Comment: Hi Jon, I have provided a small demoproject to see the results of different cast methods.

Comment: @msedi: Right - on my box at least, the performance hit of using a conversion delegate is about 20%. However, it doesn't require unsafe code, it's clean and it's flexible - I think that's a pretty reasonable trade-off. You *could* use dynamic methods to build up the specific conversion, but it'll be somewhat trickier.

Comment: Hi Jon, you are surely right that it would be nice to have the flexibility of using the method with ConvertAll. I would love to have it this way. But in fact the things I'm currently doing are very processing power intensive and time sensitive. Therefore I need to get the most out of C#. Currently I have to live with a lot of unsafes, because in mostly all the cases where I need speed the fastest option was only with unsafe code. This is also true for reading files. Do you know if there is some good resource for high performance computing in C#?

Comment: @msedi: When reading files, unsafe code shouldn't make much difference at all - you'll be IO-bound, not compute-bound. Now when I ran your code, I hardly saw *any* difference between the non-Convert methods, half of which don't need to be unsafe. So if you could dynamically build that code using DynamicMethod (but not unsafe code) would that be good enough for you?

Comment: Hi Jon, of course you are right. Reading and Writing files is another issue which I will post shortly here. And you are also right, it has nothing to do with casting. I will try to do dynamic code in my next steps, I was only hoping that .NET supports a way that I don't have to do such generic/primitive operations by my own. Although ConvertAll is such a way I hoped that it could perform better. ConvertAll is too generic for me ;-)

Comment: Just another issue that came up recently when comapring the performance data. On my colleagues machine the same code showed inverted execution time. This means the code that was slowest on my machine is fastest on his machine. Do you have an explanation for this?

Comment: @msedi: Not offhand, no... but check for 32-bit vs 64-bit differences, service packs etc.